# Ошибка типа ModelValidationException

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc

Добрый вечер. Использую Visual Studio 2015(MVC-проект). У меня есть модель:

```
 public class UserModels 
 {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    // e-mail пользователя
    public string mail { get; set; }
    //пароль пользователя
    public string password { get; set; }
 }
```

Также создан контекст данных и инициализация БД (всего одна запись для проверки):

```
  public class UserContext: DbContext
  {
    public UserContext() : base("UserContext") { }
    //получение из БД набора данных типа User
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
  }



public class UserDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UserContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(UserContext db)
    {
        db.Users.Add(new User { id = 0, mail = "sobaka453@gmail.com", password = "11111111111" });
        base.Seed(db);
    }

}
```

Есть также View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "allUsers"; }
```

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><p>Код</p></td>
            <td><p>Логин</p></td>
            <td><p>Пароль</p></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><p>@b.id</p></td>
                <td><p>@b.mail</p></td>
                <td><p>@b.password</p></td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

При запуске приложения следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы сообщение об ошибке вы опубликовали в текстовом виде. Картинка будет когда то удалена и ваша ссылка станет битой.